# how do you serialize HTML in C#?

Tags: c#, html, xml

how do you serialize HTML in C#?

I think I know how to use XSD.exe to create  C# classes from XML that can be used with the XmlSerializer class to serialize and verify the XML document.

Is there a way to do the same sort of thing with an HTML document?  I have tried but the xsd command line says that the remote name www.w3.org cannot be resolved.

At a minimum, is there a way to use C# to find out if an HTML file is valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is an open source library that parses HTML easily for you. You can then search/manipulate the structure of the document quite easily.

It's quite forgiving with the HTML you provide it, so I'm not sure if it's a good way of checking that if you've got a strict xHTML valid document. But it should be able to parse anything a modern browser can.

Answer (score 0):

If it's XHTML that you're trying to validate, you can do it like this:

```
static void validate(string filename)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler +=
        new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
    settings.XmlResolver = new XhtmlUrlResolver();

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings);

    // Parse the file. 
    while (reader.Read()) ;
}

// Display any validation errors.
private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Validation Error: {0}", e.Message);
}
```

It will be a bit slow because it's downloading the schema files from the W3C web site.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize/parse HTML, I would also recommend HTMLAgilityPack.  However, to validate the HTML, you could try running [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).  For XHTML, however, you can obtain an XSD.