# Foreach Write Headers and Footers Cleanly

Tags: c#, foreach

I often have code that goes something like this.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
IEnumberable<MyWidget> MyWidgets=GetMyWidgets();
if(MyWidgets.Count!=0)
    {
    sb.Append("This is header text");
    foreach(MyWidget widget in MyWidgets)
        {
        sb.Append("This is info about widget: "+widget.SomeInfo);
        }
    sb.Append("This is footer text");
    }
```

Is there some way to make this cleaner? Perhaps using Lambda expressions or anonymous functions (I'm not familiar with those, so an example would be helpful)?

A real-world example is writing an HTML table if there are items present in the collection of objects.

Comment: When reading this code, it is perfectly clear to me what is happening. I think 'clever' changes to it would just make it less readable. This code is directly saying what you mean. Also I see a 'clever' way to make it shorter, but it'd just be less readable. You can do `"header"+string.join("",MyWidgets.Select("bla"+widget.SomeInfo))+"footer"` , that's worse in my book though

Comment: Seems good to me­. Maybe change `MyWidgets.Count != 0` to `MyWidgets.Any()` for readability and optimization, but it's pretty good like that. Oh and maybe remove the hardcoded strings for a constant, it's easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
List<MyWidget> MyWidgets = GetMyWidgets().ToList();
if(MyWidgets.Count!=0)
{
    sb.Append("This is header text");
    MyWidgets.Foreach(w => sb.Append("This is info about widget: " + w.SomeInfo));
    sb.Append("This is footer text");
}
```

Comment: Language designers _specifically_ wanted to avoid this sort of thing and wanted developers to use foreach loops instead of MyWidgets.ForEach . See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, so don't use it then. Personally I disagree, I use it often.

Comment: I don't get why you'd get any downvotes. This is a useful solution, some people downvote stuff because it's different instead of saying what they think makes it good/bad in their opinion, it's really harmful behavior imho.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. Unfortuntely, now that I see it, I think what I posted in the OP is more readable if the .ForEach parameters are going to be anything more than a line.

Comment: @msm8bball, Personally, I've seen this so much I can read it just as fast.

Comment: @Gabe After reading all the other suggestions, yours appears to be about the cleanest implementation. I'm going to accept this answer now. Not sure if I'll end up using it, but I may find a place for it. Hopefully it serves as a useful alternative for others.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't have any problem using .Foreach() when the lambda expression is merely retrieving information from the object, as opposed to changing it. I wouldn't like something similar to this: `MyWidgets.Foreach(w => w.Modify())`

Comment: I think it's silly, at best, to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>` simply so that you can use the `ForEach` method and the `Count` property.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Why do you think it's silly to convert it into a type that you need? Simply saying "it's silly" adds nothing of value to the discussion.

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of the `List<T>` type. You just need to iterate the object you already have.

Answer (score 3):

Beside other suggestions it's important to use `Any` instead of `Count`

```
  if (MyWidgets.Any())
    {
        sb.Append("This is header text");
        sb.Append(string.Concat("", MyWidgets.Select(x => "This is info about widget: " + x.SomeInfo)));
        sb.Append("This is footer text");
    }
```

For small amount of data original version will work faster, in my case it was two times faster for 100 elements. But for larger amounts Linq is faster, in my case 10% for 100000 items selection. I'm not sure how come, but it should be due Count.

Comment: There's no reason to use `Join` if you're not going to use a separator.  If you just want to concat all of the strings together use the method that does just that, `string.Concat`.  It's both semantically correct (more important) as well as probably at least a bit more efficient.

Comment: Any idea why MyWidgets.Any() is faster for larger datasets? If I were the MS guy writing the extension method .Any() I would have just ended up using .Count in my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't really need any other kind of implementation.

The code is already clean enough as it is and the intention is perfectly clear.

@RyanWH adds:

> Using LINQ in this situation might be better if and only if it provides a necessary boost in performance. The original question wasn't concerned with speed though, so I agree that the original content is simple and easy to understand for what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can fold all this into a single statement using `string.Join`:

```
if(MyWidgets.Count() != 0) {
    sb.AppendFormat(
        "This is header text\n{0}This is footer text\n"
    ,   string.Join(
            "\n"
        ,   MyWidgets.Select(w => string.Format("This is info about widget: {0}\n", w))
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you take something that was clean and clear and make it harder to read.

Comment: @Jetti The thing is, the easiness/hardness to read is highly subjective, and it is strongly correlated to one's familiarity with relevant technologies and APIs in question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight would you _honestly_ say this version is more readable than what OP originally had? I mean I agree it's better than forEach because we're mapping here, but the original is perfectly clear.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Absolutely! I *routinely* use code precisely like this in my production code for some 5 years (most of my `ToString` implementations for objects with aggregations look like this). Nobody in our company complains about the use of `Join` or `Format`, it's very neat and clean.

Comment: I definitely like this approach.

Comment: The OP didn't use `AppendLine`, so this is adding newlines into the solution that weren't there before.

Comment: @Servy That's true, I added `\n`-s so that headers and footers looked more like headers and footers, as opposed to prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm just pointing out the difference.  It's hard to say if it was a mistake of the OP's or intentional.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight

What I wrote in the OP was not actual code I am using, but instead intended to represent what I do (and I suspect others follow this pattern too). So while my example didn't include line endings and I used Append instead of AppendLine, that was simply for brevity's sake because it's not central to the point I'm trying to get across.

Comment: @msm8bball That was my guess, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a `string.Join` will improve the readability. And since, with that, you're no longer doing many appends, simple string concatenation will be just fine.

```
string str = "";
IEnumerable<MyWidget> MyWidgets=GetMyWidgets();
if(MyWidgets.Any())
{
    str += "This is header text\n";
    str += string.Join("\n", MyWidgets.Select(x => "This is info about widget: "
                                                   + x.SomeInfo));
    str += "\nThis is footer text";
}
```

Comment: He's not using `AppendLine`, so there shouldn't be a bunch of newline separators.

Comment: Why would you omit `StringBuilder`, this seems regressive.

Comment: @Gabe Because he's removing the vast majority of the appends, namely those in a loop, so it's no longer going to be a performance problem to use `string.Concat`.

Comment: @Servy well, yeah, but as-is it would make the text run together (e.g. `"This is header textThis is info about widget: somethingThis is footer text"`). I figured some sort of separator would help, and put it newlines. The asker can feel free to remove or replace these, obviously; doesn't affect my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this:

```
foreach(MyWidget widget in MyWidgets)
{
    sb.Append("This is info about widget: "+widget.SomeInfo);
}
```

With this:

```
MyWidgets.ToList().ForEach(x => sb.Append("This is info about widget: "+ x.SomeInfo);
```

Comment: MyWidgets doesn't have a ForEach, LINQ is a query language. you need to convert it to a list.

Comment: I see the first (existing code) as being cleaner - there's a reason `ForEach` was left out of LINQ. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: This is dreadful. You'd create a new list, add everything in widgets to the list, just so you could use the `ForEach` method? Even if you ignore the fact that using **methods** like `ForEach` is frowned on, why not write your own extension method on IEnumerable? No new list created, no overheard of allocating, adding to and then collecting said list. e.g (forgive formatting) `public static class Extns { public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action){ foreach(var item in items) action(item);}}`

Comment: Completely valid point, I rushed into answering that without thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting exactly what you have there into a function?  There's nothing wrong with that implementation and it isn't 'dirty' in any sense of the word.  Putting code on fewer lines doesn't necessarily mean it's better.  You can have a generic collection of generic items as the input parameter and return the string builder.  It's far better to remove any copypasta'd code you have in your project than to minimize the number of lines of a simple routine like this one.

If you're talking about possibly doing XML or HTML serialization, there are already tools that do that for you.  C# combines a declarative way of including things in XML and I imagine there's a library out there to do the same thing for HTML.  In fact, googling C# html serialization leads you to several useful posts here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I googled "c# html serialization" but most of the results I got looked like overkill for writing a simple HTML table or including a list of items in an email. Did you have any specific Stack Overflow page in mind that I should take a look at?

Comment: I didn't have one in mind, but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793885/how-do-you-serialize-html-in-c) looks pretty useful.  I haven't used HTMLAgilityPack but it looks like it can get the job done.

Comment: It doesn't appear on first glance the HTMLAgilityPack provides much use for creating HTML. Looks to be the other way around.

And it looks like overkill for situations like writing a simple table or bullet-ed list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the changes I would personally do. I think private methods are much more expressive than trying to LINQ-idize everything, in my opinion.
I'd also consider changing the hardcoded values for constants, to help maintainability.

```
public string YourMethod()
{
    string text = string.Empty;
    IEnumberable<MyWidget> MyWidgets = GetMyWidgets();

    if(MyWidgets.Any())
    {
        text += "This is header text";
        text +=  GetInfoFromWidgets(MyWidgets);
        text += "This is footer text";
    }

    return text;
}

private string GetInfoFromWidgets(IEnumerable<MyWidget> widgets)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(MyWidget widget in MyWidgets)
    {
        sb.Append("This is info about widget: "+widget.SomeInfo);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Since you combine strings so much, using a StringBuilder would be better.

Comment: I use it in the private method. The main one only have 3 strings to append, so I prefer using string directly. Could use two SBs or send it via parameter, but if the performance isn't impacted I find it cleaner that way.

Comment: LINQ is like beer. It's great, but use it in moderation or things gets blurry.

Comment: Would you really personally use this over what I posted in the OP, or some of other suggestions? This ends up looking very verbose and seems to add complexity instead of simplify. I guess I just don't see the advantage in this one.

Comment: Depends how you define complexity. I find more complex a method doing multiple things than two methods doing a single thing. In this case, I can just take a quick look, see that I add info from widgets and skip the details of how it is performed because I don't care. If someday I need to know how I get the info, then I can look at the private method. But that's just how I see things, I know people often find it easier having everything in the same bunch of code.

Comment: I tend to put code that's going to be called by other functions into their own methods, to promote re-use. But simply putting it into another function for the sake of reducing the size of the function is something I stray away from. If the function does grow too large, then I'm probably doing something wrong anyways.